# Rational multiples of pi cannot be an arctangent of a rational number (other than 0, 1, -1)

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Is there a theorem asserting
$$ \arctan(\mathbb{Q}\backslash\{0,1,-1\}) \cap (\pi\mathbb{Q}) = \varnothing $$?

As hints in the comments [Niven's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niven%27s_theorem) asserts the equality, so it is possible to extend to algebraic numbers $\mathbb{A}$ as the set of all roots of polynomials with integer coefficients, namely
$$ \arctan(\mathbb{Q}\backslash\{0,1,-1\}) \cap (\pi\mathbb{A}) = \varnothing ? $$

Comment: Niven's theorem if I recall correctly

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger: Niven's theorem is about  $\sin$ function, not $\tan$ which is needed here.

Comment: @markvs : [Niven's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niven%27s_theorem) directly addresses sine and cosine, and hence secant and cosecant as trivial corollaries.  With a little more work, the result extends to tangent and cotangent and all of these are called "Niven's theorem".

Comment: @EricTowers: It can be proved the same way as Niven's theorem, but there are angles, say $\pi/6$, such that $\sin(\theta)$ is rational, but $\tan(\theta)$ is not.

Comment: @marks : You seem to be putting claims in my mouth that I am not making.  You could just go read Niven.  The development in Bennett, Glass, Szekely, https://www.jstor.org/stable/4145241?origin=crossref , is a bit more readable.

Comment: @markvs The Wikipedia page mentions $\tan$. In any case, the $\sin$ result implies the $\cos$ result because $\cos(x)=\sin(\pi/2-x)$. Less trivially, the $\cos$ result implies the $\tan$ result because$$\tan^2(x)=\dfrac2{1+\cos(2x)}-1,$$so the only rational possibilities for $\tan^2$ are $0$, $\frac13$, $1$, and $3$, and of these, only $0$ and $1$ are squares of rationals.

Comment: For your follow-up question, see Theorem 1 here: http://www.naturalspublishing.com/files/published/j2s8h5c33e8ci4.pdf

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger: Yes, the Wikipedia article mentions tan: "The theorem extends to the other trigonometric functions as well." And yes, the proof is not hard.

Comment: @EricTowers:  I don't put claims in your mouth. You make claims on your own. Some of them contradict each other.